# JavaScript pre-emptive programming?

Tags: javascript

I want a similar effect to the following:

```
function modify() {
s.innerText='hello';
j=0;
for (i=1;i<1000000;i++) j+=i;
s.innerText=j;
}

<span id='s' onClick="modify();">Click</span>
```

When you click the object, the span element should say 'hello', the loop should add the integers from 1 to 1000000, and then the result placed in the span element. But when I click 'click', it goes straight to the answer without displaying 'hello'.

Comment: Computers can count up to 1000000 really fast.

Comment: `setTimeout()` will be your friend here.

Comment: So why if you want to change the color, do you show us text change?

Comment: @j08691 I think In this case it will not do anything right ? (compiler optimization)

Comment: You probably forgot the loop body, but the answer holds true: browsers don't render anything until javascript finishes. So if you have several DOM changes in a row, you'll only see the last one.

Comment: "Page painter" and "JS runner" work in one thread together. "Painter" repaints the page when "runner" frees the thread context and vice versa

Comment: JavaScript has no concept of pre-emption in the browser.

Comment: You should use `var` when you initialize variable in the local scope. This for loop would be optimized as `var i = 1000000;` I guess, even less time that you would expect.

Comment: found a way out here - change the loop to an alert and it works, but I guess this is for similar reasons to dizel3d gave

Comment: If you were wondering, the effect is a piano key. When pressed it lights up.I have p1=new Audio('Piano11.mp3','audio/mpeg');function note(s,sn) {
s.currentTime=0;
s.play();
}<td><div onClick='note(q1,1);'></div></td>, with a stylesheet, but when you press the key (div) and try to change the color nothing happens (sounds at https://archive.org/details/SynthesizedPianoNotes - community site)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `#setTimeout()` function of the `window` object if you want to wait for a time.

```
function modify() {
    s.textContent = 'hello';
    setTimeout( function () {
        s.textContent = 'goodbye';
    }, 1000);
}
```

This will wait for a second (1000 ms) before changing the text. (I also changed the IE specific `innerText` to the standard `textContent` property)

Comment: the idea wasn't really just to do nothing for a bit - the code doesn't ever show hello even if you are doing something with a purpose. And I don't know how long the execution time is between the 'go' and 'stop' phases. But nice solution anyway.

Comment: Yes, that issue was addressed in the comment of @georg. This method works, because we actually leave the function when setTimeout is called, and the DOM is updated.